# How to make submit button in form fit inline with text

Tags: html, forms, button, submit

I built a webpage for a professor at USF. I was wondering how to make the form submit button in the image below show up inline with the text. It looks sort of funny as is.

My current code is,

```
<div>The term $table is not in DDIRANK, but there are enough search         results on PubMed for us to add it. To add the term, please click this button<form action=\"add_term.php\" target=\"_blank\" method=\"post\"><input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$table\" name=\"add\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add $table to database\"></form> and wait for the page to load.</div>;
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the submit button inline with the text field you will need to go to add `float: left;` to the button's CSS.

Declare the CSS attribute like so:
`<form style="float: left">...`